# Copy vs move in std::pair braced initialization

Tags: c++, templates, initialization, move-semantics, std-pair

I have the following code and its output printed below. I can't seem to understand why one set of braced initialization results in the move constructor being called, while the other results in the copy constructor. I have somewhat narrowed it down to direct-list-initialization vs copy-list-initialization per https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization
I just can't quite figure out which case my code belongs to. Thanks in advance.

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct Foo {
  Foo() {
    cout << "create foo\n";
  }

  ~Foo() {
    cout << "delete foo\n";
  }

  Foo(const Foo& f) {
    cout << "copy foo\n";
  }

  Foo(Foo&& f) noexcept {
    cout << "move foo\n";
  }

  Foo& operator=(const Foo& f) = delete;

  Foo& operator=(Foo&& f) = delete;
};

int32_t main() {
  pair<uint32_t, Foo> f1{0, Foo{}};  // Calls move ctor
  cout << "------------------------\n";

  pair<uint32_t, Foo> f2{0, {}};     // Calls copy ctor
  cout << "------------------------\n";

  return 0;
}
```

This results in

```
create foo

move foo

delete foo

------------------------

create foo

copy foo

delete foo

------------------------

delete foo

delete foo
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's take a look at two of the two-argument constructors of `pair`: [[pairs.pair]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/pairs.pair)

```
EXPLICIT constexpr pair(const T1& x, const T2& y);
template<class U1, class U2> EXPLICIT constexpr pair(U1&& x, U2&& y);
```

The second constructor uses perfect forwarding, and `U2` cannot be deduced from `{}`.  Therefore, the first version is selected when `{}` is used.  When `Foo{}` is used instead, the argument has type `Foo`, so `U2` is deduced to be `Foo`, causing the forwarding version to be selected.

Comment: While your explanation makes sense about the compiler choosing which version to call, I can't seem to convince myself that it is indeed the case.

I specified the Foo constructor as 'explicit' and I get an error that reads:
error: converting to 'const Foo' from initializer list would use explicit constructor 'Foo::Foo()'

Comment: @tree Are you using C++17?  In C++17, both of these constructors are conditionally `explicit`, i.e., `explicit` if any of the constructors they need call is `explicit`.  They were unconditionally `explicit` in previous versions, and the change to conditional `explicit` was applied as a Defect Report.

Comment: Yes, I am using c++17.
So what you're saying is because I declared my Foo constructor explicit, I MUST use `Foo{}` instead of `{}`.

Comment: @tree Oh, you mean the compiler rejected `{}`?  Yeah, in that case `explicit` constructors are not considered, since argument passing is copy-initialization (i.e., non-`explicit` initialization).

Comment: Yes, the moment I added the `explicit` to the Foo constructor,  the compiler rejected the `{}` initialization for `Foo`

Comment: @tree Yeah, I meant to say that argument passing uses copy-initialization, so passing `{}` as an argument is like using `const T2& y = {}` to initialize the parameter `y`

Comment: Let me see if I understand...
Because I specified the `Foo` constructor as `explicit`, the way to think about the correct way to initialize it would be `const T2& y = Foo{}`?

Comment: @tree Yes.  So passing `Foo{}` to a parameter will work fine too.

Comment: Let me try to summarize what I've learned...
The compiler can't determine the type for the perfect fowarding `std::pair` constructor when using `{}` to initialize `Foo` because the type is missing, therefore the next best match is the `std::pair` copy constructor where the `Foo` argument is `const T2& y` which results in `Foo`'s copy constructor being called. By adding `explicit` to `Foo`s constructor, the compiler rejects the implicit construction of `Foo` when it matches `const T2& y`